# Does google map API work without billing address?

Tags: google-cloud-billing

It is not accepting any of my cards. Please help me which card is required for billing address or is it possible to use map API without billing address?

Comment: Did you check [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used to be possible, but not any more.
However, the good new are:
You won't be charged until your usage exceeds $200 in a month. Note that the Maps Embed API, Maps SDK for Android, and Maps SDK for iOS currently have no usage limits and are at no charge (usage of the API or SDKs is not applied against your $200 monthly credit).

Note that they will verify your card by making a small transaction (like 1 dollar or something)

If you are having an error while you are registering a card:

- Make sure your card & address information is up to date
- Submit any extra information that is requested
- Check you have sufficient funds for the purchase
- Contact your bank or card issuer

You may fix your issue by visiting this one: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2523116?hl=en

Or

You can contact them to help you about your cards here: https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/?hl=en#topic=9017576